# implement a button in table, when clicked, open a dialog box, displays the values of a specific cell as Dropdown/ checkbox button

Tags: java, jquery, oracle, sqlplus

So I want to implement a button for each row in my table.

Now, The functionality that I want my button to provide is:

CLICK -> OPENS A DIALOG BOX -> DISPLAY THE VALUE FROM A SPECIFIC CELL  (which is in the same row as the button) -> DISPLAYS THE VALUES AS A DROPDOWN OR CHECKBOX BUTTONS.

The value in the cell are being populated by using ResultSet.getString method taking the values from a database.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This question is too broad.

Comment: I dont know if I can rephrase my question here or should I post it again. I will still post it again here itself. 

How to implement a drop down menu of values from a specific cell in a table. ?

Comment: OldProgrammer just trying to say your question is too broad; if you read those links he offered, you may see that we don't know if this is a web-based solution (maybe), what tools you plan to use (sqlplus is not a valid tag here), tomcat? PHP???

Comment: I'm not sure what a 'table' is here. It doesn't seem to be a database table exactly.